# Long if statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am building a computing project for my school coursework and I have a fairly large `if` statement. When I run the program it isn't slow at all, but I was just wondering if it is considered bad to write large `if` statements.

```
    For BookingNumber = 0 To intBookingCount - 1
            If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 1 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton1.Enabled = False
                If intLength(BookingNumber) = 1 Then
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
                    radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 3 Then
                    radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 4 Then
                    radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 5 Then
                    radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 6 Then
                    radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 7 Then
                    radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
                End If
            ElseIf intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 2 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
                If intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 3 Then
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 4 Then
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 5 Then
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 6 Then
                    radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
                End If
            ElseIf intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 3 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
                If intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 3 Then
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 4 Then
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 5 Then
                    radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
                End If
            ElseIf intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 4 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
                If intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 3 Then
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 4 Then
                    radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
                End If
            ElseIf intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 5 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
                If intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                ElseIf intLength(BookingNumber) = 3 Then
                    radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                    radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
                End If
            ElseIf intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 6 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
                If intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
                    radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
                End If
            ElseIf intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 7 And strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR Then
                radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Show us - we have no idea what you mean if we can't see the code.

Comment: Yes, I used to create long if statements but I find them hard to debug, if there is a problem with the statement you won't know where the problem is, it's bad form to have large if statements

Comment: Depends on how comprehensible it is. Don't like 'em myself too easy to get lost.

Comment: Something along those lines

Comment: That I have to say is 'orrible. Where are they enabled so this code can conditionally disable them?

Comment: I mean it may be fairly difficult for you to follow but the person who would maintain it would get a tutorial of what does what and how to add to it.

Comment: What do you think would be a better way of laying it out?

Comment: There's no `switch` in vb.net??

Comment: And you can't make an array of radioButtons?

Comment: Give me a while I see a pattern in there.

Comment: @HenryPenton When you get out into the real world, you'll find that when you write code that's difficult to follow, it will be you who gets picked to change it, and it will be a version later and you'll find it difficult to follow.

Comment: If you were given a table of rules to implement, it helps if that table ends up in code pretty much the same way as the rules were written. This way, you can quickly update things when the rules change, and the equivalence is easy to see. If you get handed an exploded set of rules multiplied with each other, factor the common bits out ON PAPER, check with the ruleswriter, then implement the simpler version.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes, Select Case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I take it back, you can replace **ALL** of your code with this:

```
For BookingNumber = 0 To intBookingCount - 1

    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 1 Then radRadioButton1.Enabled = False
    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 2 Then radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 3 Then radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 4 Then radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 5 Then radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 6 Then radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
    If intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) = 7 Then radRadioButton7.Enabled = False

    Dim total = intStartPeriod(BookingNumber) + intLength(BookingNumber)
    If total >= 3 Then radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
    If total >= 4 Then radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
    If total >= 5 Then radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
    If total >= 6 Then radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
    If total >= 7 Then radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
    If total >= 8 Then radRadioButton7.Enabled = False

Next
```

Massive if-blocks are hugely frowned upon. In general, it's best to factor them out if at all possible. For example, you'll often see something along the lines of

```
Sub DoStuff()
    If conditionA Then
        DoSomeStuff()
        If conditionB Then
            DoMoreStuff()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This can be refactored as:

```
Sub DoStuff()
    If Not conditionA Then Return

    DoSomeStuff()

    If Not conditionB Then Return

    DoMoreStuff()
End Sub
```

I asked a similar (not the same) question a while back and got this very helpful answer:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/174977/57863

Which linked to:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/172910/57863

Some great links were offered on the subject of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read, but proper indentation can alleviate that.  It may also be a sign that you're code requires some refactoring.  As an example, really long `if` statements can be written like this:

```
if (condition == A && condition == C 
        && (someCondition >= 1000 || someOtherCondition != C) 
        || someThirdCondition == D) {

    ...

}
```

Also, be sure to take advantage of short-circuited boolean statements and put the easiest to evaluate expression first.

Comment: Does VB even have short-circuiting?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - The equivalent of `&&` would be `AndAlso` instead of `And`. AndAlso "short-circuits" whereas And will evaluate both expressions regardless of the outcome of the first.

Comment: Well I have used for loops which increment the value of something rather than writing the same if statement out 7 times, personally I find it very easy to find the bit I want to edit, so I was just wondered if it was acceptable, it didn't really seem like the correct place to use a switch statement.

Comment: Think it depends on what version. IThey introduced AndAlso and OrElse at some point.

Comment: My fault... I reverted to my more typical Java when writing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
For BookingNumber = 0 To intBookingCount - 1
  bookingNumberLength = intLength(BookingNumber)
  If strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR then
    Select Case intStartPeriod(BookingNumber)
      Case 1
        radRadioButton1.Enabled = False
        Select Case bookingNumberLength
          Case 2
            radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
          Case 3
            radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
          Case 4
            radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
          Case 5
            radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
          Case 6
            radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
          Case 7
            radRadioButton2.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton3.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton4.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton5.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
            radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
         End Select
      Case 2
      Case 3
      Case 4
      Case 5
      Case 6
        radRadioButton6.Enabled = False
        If intLength(BookingNumber) = 2 Then
          radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
        End If
      Case 7
        radRadioButton7.Enabled = False
    End Select 
  End If
Next
```

Look for simplifying things when you do this your code didn't do anything unless strComputerRoom(BookingNumber) = strCR.

It doesn't look like a big deal but if you start chopping out things like this you get get to the meat of things.

Note might have stuffed up the VB as I'm a C# boy, and I'm going to let you fill in the rest of it...
Me I'd be having those radio buttons in an array and then it would be just a question of changing all that if and elseing to come up with  something like a start and end for the loop and after you've sussed them.

```
For rb = rbStart To rbEnd
  MyButtons[rb].Enabled = False
Next
```

Looking at it you could work out start and with with a couple of lines of math. Might challenge your teacher though, and I don't know how far on your are. When you give then this in about five lines of code they might get suspicious and you won't learn nuffin' if I do it for you.

Programmer rule #21 - We don't like to do a lot of typing.